# react native can't download npm in terminal

Tags: reactjs, react-native

today downloaded react tools and want to start working whith react native.
For this I need to install npm
but when i use command

```
npm i -g expo-cli
```

### it returns some error:

npm : The name "npm" is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or executable program. Please check that your name is spelled correctly and that you have
and the path is correct, then try again.
line:1 character:1

- npm i -g expo-cli
- ```
     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
  ```

---

pls help what to do?
thx so far

discribed in previous window

Comment: Did you run node -v and npm -v in your terminal before running npm i -g expo-cli?

Answer (score 0):

First make sure node.js is installed on your device. To do this simply type in the terminal:

```
node -v
```

If a version number does not display, then you need to install node. You can refer to the link below.

https://nodejs.org/en/learn/getting-started/how-to-install-nodejs

If a version number does display then you have node downloaded and should have access to npm as well. If this is the case then you likely need to check your PATH to ensure that npm is able to be accessed correctly.

To do this, first locate the location of the npm files on your device. Mine is located in "C:\Users[username]\AppData\Roaming\npm".

When this is located you must then click on the windows home button and type in "Edit the system environement variables". This will open the "System Properties" window. Click "Environment Variables". IN the upper section you will see the user variables with one of them being titled "Path". If you then highlight this and click "Edit", it will show all the path variables that have been created. You can then click "New" and paste the path of the npm files. Then click "Ok" to close out these tabs.

You will have to then restart your terminal, but if you type:

```
npm -v
```

It should show the npm version. If it does then you should be able to successfully use npm in your project.

Hope this helps